# Vue.js Declarative rendering not working after webpacking

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js

Below is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
  <body>
    <h1>ES</h1>
    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
      </div> 
      <script src="dist/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use basic vue.js declarative rendering. My index.js input for webpack with zero configuration  is below

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  })
```

The value of message is not shown in the page . Is this something to do with my webpack configuration. Do I need to use Babel transpiler to get this to work?
[image]

Comment: Your `<head>` and `<body>` tags are incorrectly nested.

Answer (score 1):

See   [Explanation of Different Builds](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds) in the doc.

> The default file for these bundlers (pkg.module) is the Runtime only
> ES Module build (vue.runtime.esm.js).

Vue build with runtime only **doesn't include HTML template compiler**, which you need in your case. (Runtime only build is 30% smaller in size)

As the doc mentioned, to import full build of Vue, you may use

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js';
```

Btw, I highly recommend you to use vue-cli instead of configuring the Vue project yourself.